# Ruby Hash creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in Ruby and I am trying to learn Ruby these day. I was going through Hash today and got stuck in problem related to Hash

I have the following Hash

```
{"key1" => ["param_1","param_2"], "key2" => ["param_3","param_4"], "key3" => "param_5", "key4" => "param_6","key5" => ["param_7","param_8"]}
```

and I want to convert the above Hash into the following.

```
{"my_hash" => [ {"name" => "key1","value" => ["param_1","param_2"]},
                {"name" => "key2","value" => ["param_3","param_4"]},
                {"name" => "key3","value" => ["param_5"]},
                {"name" => "key4","value" => ["param_6"]},
                {"name" => "key5","value" => ["param_7","param_8"]}
              ]
}
```

Can someone show me how can i do it in Ruby in a efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hsh = {"key1" => ["param_1","param_2"],
       "key2" => ["param_3","param_4"], "key3" => "param_5", 
      "key4" => "param_6","key5" => ["param_7","param_8"]}
hsh.map{|k,v| {name: k,value: Array(v) }}
# => [{:name=>"key1", :value=>["param_1", "param_2"]},
#     {:name=>"key2", :value=>["param_3", "param_4"]},
#     {:name=>"key3", :value=>["param_5"]},
#     {:name=>"key4", :value=>["param_6"]},
#     {:name=>"key5", :value=>["param_7", "param_8"]}]
```

---

```
hsh = {"key1" => ["param_1","param_2"],
       "key2" => ["param_3","param_4"], "key3" => "param_5", 
      "key4" => "param_6","key5" => ["param_7","param_8"]}
hsh.map{|k,v| {"name" => k,"value" => Array(v) }}
# => [{"name"=>"key1", "value"=>["param_1", "param_2"]},
#     {"name"=>"key2", "value"=>["param_3", "param_4"]},
#     {"name"=>"key3", "value"=>["param_5"]},
#     {"name"=>"key4", "value"=>["param_6"]},
#     {"name"=>"key5", "value"=>["param_7", "param_8"]}]
```

Comment: Note that this answer uses symbols as keys instead of strings, e.g. `:name` instead of `"name"`. Using symbols as keys is the standard for Ruby. You (the asker) should only need strings if you're trying to produce a Hash that can easily be exported to [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: Instead of `value: v.is_a?(Array) ? v : [v]`, you can just use [`#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_a), like `value: v.to_a`. `to_a` converts a value to an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) by wrapping it inside an array, unless it's already an Array.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane You cannot depend on the `to_a` method being defined for an arbitrary object. `[v].flatten` might be a more forgiving approach.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane see this entry - `"key3" => "param_5"`.. if i use `#to_a`,then error will be thorwn out..

Comment: @tadman thanks for pointing to the `Array#flatten`... I forgot that for a while..